# Formulate the solution of a zero sum game with a payoff matrix A as an optimization problem.

Tags: optimization, constraints, non-smooth-optimization

let $x\in$ ${\Bbb R}^n$ be the strategy of the first player and let $y\in$ ${\Bbb R}^n$ be the strategy of the second player. That is, $x_i$ represents the probability of the first player taking the action i.The first player aims to maximize the payoff, while the second player aims to minimize the payoff.  The payoff matrix is $A\in$ ${\Bbb R}^{nxn}$.
The solution to a zero-sum game can be formulated as the following non-smooth optimization problem. Let f(x) be the payoff for a strategy of the first player, defined as:
$f(x)=min_yx^TAy$ $\space$ s.t. $\space 1^Ty=1,y>= 0$
The first player needs to optimize for the best strategy as:
$max_xf(x)\space\space s.t.\space\space 1^Tx=1,x>=0$
Reformulate this optimization problem to a smooth (linear) constrained optimization problem. That mean there should be only one maximization or minimization.  Also all the constraints and the objective should be linear.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry,I still learn the basic concepts of zero sum game in wikipedia.I still don't know how to start in this question